# Удаление дочерних элементов в многоуровневом меню

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица `menu` с колонками: `id`, `value`, `id_parent`. И есть многоуровневое меню:

```
Item0
    Item1
        Item2
        Item3
            Item4
```

Нужно, чтобы при удалении `Item1` удалялись `Item2`, `Item3` и `Item4`. Это можно реализовать при помощи MySQL не разбивая эту таблицу на 2 таблицы?
Например, добавить внешний ключ:

```
ALTER TABLE menu
ADD CONSTRAINT menu_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id_parent) REFERENCES menu (id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Но не срабатывает, пишет ошибка в синтаксисе, не могу разобраться... И можно ли так вообще?

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: да уже разобрался, спасибо